# Capture ContentService return from Google Sheet with javascript on the page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a web form that gathers some data from users, then sent the data to Google Sheet with doPost(). Now I need to capture the ContentService returned to my with javascript, so I could display some feedbacks on the same page with that web form. I have tried to set the "target" attribute of the form to some hidden iframe, and I keep getting "script.googleusercontent.com refused to connect".  So my question is, what is the best way to capture the content service object return by Google Sheet without directing my users to another page or reloading the current page?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code you're working on?

Comment: just post it to `/exec`. Why are you posting it to a hidden iframe?